# Help understanding Bayesian Regression versus Frequentist Regression

Tags: regression, bayesian, regression-coefficients, model-comparison

I'm trying to wrap my head around this and hope that someone can maybe explain it to me in a simple way.

I built two models:

1. A frequentist regression
2. A Bayesian regression with some priors

Here is an example using data that is the height and weight of adult women:

```r
    library(tidyverse)
    library(rstanarm)
    
    df <- datasets::women %>%
      mutate(height_c = height - mean(height))
    
    fit_ols <- lm(weight ~ height_c, data = df)
    
    fit_stan <- stan_glm(weight ~ height_c, data = df,
                         prior = normal(63.7, 5),
                         prior_intercept = normal(170, 20))
```

Looking at the coefficients of these two models, they are nearly identical:

```r
    coef(fit_ols)
    coef(fit_stan)
    
    > coef(fit_ols)
    (Intercept)    height_c 
       136.7333      3.4500 
    > coef(fit_stan)
    (Intercept)    height_c 
     136.736551    3.456117
```

They also make very similar predictions of body weight:

```r
    df <- df %>%
      mutate(predict_ols = predict(fit_ols, newdata = .),
             predict_stan = predict(fit_stan, newdata = .))
     
    df
    
    > df
       height weight height_c predict_ols predict_stan
    1      58    115       -7    112.5833     112.5705
    2      59    117       -6    116.0333     116.0237
    3      60    120       -5    119.4833     119.4770
    4      61    123       -4    122.9333     122.9302
    5      62    126       -3    126.3833     126.3834
    6      63    129       -2    129.8333     129.8367
    7      64    132       -1    133.2833     133.2899
    8      65    135        0    136.7333     136.7432
    9      66    139        1    140.1833     140.1964
    10     67    142        2    143.6333     143.6496
    11     68    146        3    147.0833     147.1029
    12     69    150        4    150.5333     150.5561
    13     70    154        5    153.9833     154.0094
    14     71    159        6    157.4333     157.4626
    15     72    164        7    160.8833     160.9158
```

I'm curious as to why my `stan` model does have coefficients that are pulled closer to my priors? I tried this with even small data, in the hopes to see the `stan` model diverge from the frequentist model and more closely reflect my prior knowledge, to no avail:

```r
    set.seed(4873)
    df_small <- df %>%
      sample_n(8)
    
    df_small %>%
      summarize(avg_hgt = mean(height),
                sd_hgt = sd(height),
                avg_wgt = mean(weight),
                sd_wgt = sd(weight))
    
    fit_ols_small <- lm(weight ~ height_c, data = df_small)
    
    fit_stan_small <- stan_glm(weight ~ height_c, data = df_small,
                         prior = normal(63.7, 5),
                         prior_intercept = normal(170, 20))
    
    coef(fit_ols_small)
    coef(fit_stan_small)
    
    > coef(fit_ols_small)
    (Intercept)    height_c 
     136.533990    3.636453 
    > coef(fit_stan_small)
    (Intercept)    height_c 
     136.532238    3.641111
```

What am I missing here or what am I doing wrong? Shouldn't my prior knowledge in some way be reflected here, otherwise, why wouldn't I just use the frequentist approach to linear regression (other than the fact that I can get other info from the Bayes model, like posterior simulations that allow me to create a distribution of possible outcomes).

Comment: How big is the training set? If you have a lot of data, the likelihood will dominate the prior and both models will give similar results.  Also can you explain the choice of prior (I am not that familiar with STAN)

Comment: Could you try using less vague priors and tell us the results?

Comment: The training set is a set of 15 observations of women's height and weight. The prior I chose were simply ones that I googled to find "average weight and height of women". With less vague priors, the results are the same.